# Area in which $x+2{ x }^{ 2 }\sin(\frac { 1 }{ x } )$ is increasing

Tags: real-analysis

How would you define the area around $0$ in which:

> $f(x)=x+2{ x }^{ 2 }\sin(\frac { 1 }{ x } )$
>
> $(f'(0)=1)$

is increasing?

It's not a neighbourhood of $0$ or an interval which contains $0$.

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal yeah, I know. I'll try to edit it and explain.

Comment: @Paz If anything, your edit makes it *less* clear.  You're set is $\{x:f'(x)>0\}$.  You don't need to define it, you need to *describe* it, as you said originally.

Comment: @MarkMcClure: So the only term would be "set"?

Comment: I'm not certain what you mean. I certainly think that the word "set" would be more appropriate than the word "area" in your question.

Comment: @MarkMcClure: I was asking for the mathematical term most accurate to describe these points. I thought there might be a more specific term than "set", but maybe there isn't.

Answer (score 1):

You might take a look at a [plot of the derivative](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20d/dx%20x%20%2b%202%20x%5E2%20sin%281/x%29).  It's often positive and often negative in a neighborhood of the origin.  This is why the [plot of the function itself](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20x%20%2b%202%20x%5E2%20sin%281/x%29) has the jagged appearance that it has.  Examining the formula for the derivative itself, it's not hard to see why it's bounces across the $x$-axis infinitely many times in a neighborhood of the origin.